# Install a dotnet executable into PATH on linux

Tags: .net, linux, .net-core

I'm trying to build my executable and then "install" it by copying it into `/usr/local/bin`, so it can be run in bash directly.

I build my project like this:

```sh
$ dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -r linux-x64 -o out
```

This creates a directory like this (it also contains many `.DLL` files):

```sh
$ ls bionitio/out/bionitio*
bionitio/out/bionitio
bionitio/out/bionitio.deps.json
bionitio/out/bionitio.dll
bionitio/out/bionitio.pdb
bionitio/out/bionitio.runtimeconfig.json
[...]
```

I can then execute it directly, which works fine:

```sh
$ bionitio/out/bionitio --help


Usage: bionitio [arguments] [options]
```

But if I copy it to somewhere more global, it fails:

```
$ cp bionitio/out/bionitio /usr/local/bin
$ /usr/local/bin/bionitio --help
A fatal error occurred, the required library libhostfxr.so could not be found at /usr/local/bin/
```

However, I'm using the `--self-contained` flag to build this, so why is it still depending on `libhostfxr.so`?

Comment: "so why is it still depending on libhostfxr.so" .. no idea. You could try deploying it to a 'normal' folder then symlinking it into /bin/

Comment: If .NET Core is not installed into default location, then check https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/9114

Comment: `ldd /usr/local/bin/bionitio` should tell you what the runtime linker sees. I'm guessing you need to build your shared objects/dll's with `-Wl,-R,'$ORIGIN/../lib' -Wl,--enable-new-dtags`. I'm not sure if it is possible with Microsoft tools. Maybe you can change the runtime path with `chrpath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*self-contained* option publishes the runtime with the application, it's published in the same directory, not packaged in a single output file.

It removes the dependency of installed framework on target machine. You need to copy all published files to the directory where you want to run the application from.

> --self-contained
>
> Publishes the .NET Core runtime with your application so the runtime
>   doesn't need to be installed on the target machine. If a runtime
>   identifier is specified, its default value is true.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish